# 2 years and 30 weeks to import blocks?

Tags: litecoin, synchronization

Im using litecoin and it says its gonna take 2 years to import blocks heres a screenshot:

[image]

i have bootstrap.dat

Comment: It indicates up to where you've synchronized. Not how long it's going to take to synchronize the rest.

Answer (score 3):

This is a misconception and applies to everything based off Bitcoin's UI for the functions.

The bar at the bottom of the User Interface is not the "time to sync".  It's stating the last day/date (and how far in the past) the last synced block had on it.  Your client hasn't yet imported the rest of the blocks, so in a while it'll say 1 year or such.

That should decrease and reduce in the "how far in the past is the last synced block" value rapidly, as your computer churns through the blocks and imports and processes them.